How can I find the location of all swimming pools in a given area (e.g., a city)?
I like to swim when I go to a new area due to travel,  so I want a solution to find the location of all swimming pools in that given area (e.g., a city) to see which one I could use. How can I do so?
One strategy is looking at some satellite images, e.g with Google Maps, but it requires manual work and miss indoor pools. I could write some object segmentation code to automatically identify the swimming food on satellite images, but I'd prefer not to do it if a solution already exists.
Another strategy is to find the most expensive hotels, which typically come with pools, but that also requires manual work, which I'd prefer to minimize.
Lastly, one can search for "swimming pools" in Google Maps but that misses a fair amount of pools, especially in poorly mapped areas.
Is there a better strategy? Better = higher recall, reasonable precision, while minimizing human time.

Maybe openstreetmap has a layer but I suspect it would be likely to miss hotel pools. You'd likely need qgis to query it, and it might not run on mobile devices (I know of it; haven't used it).

Your search for swimming pools also needs to take into account whether the pool is actually open for use at a hotel.  They may only be open during a particular season.     For where I travel most hotels have pools, but a lot of them tend to only have outdoor pools which are closed during winter months.

@PeterM thanks, yes good point, that'd be ideal.

The other problem with satellite images is you may also see pools belonging to private homes. In some areas there may be a lot of those.

Just contact the local tourist information office?

@Berend thanks, that's assuming that they exist and that they know the information, not to mention that they sometimes can only be reached in person.

You do not need all swimming pools. You need those pools available for people like you, who will visit once or a few times in a limited period, when the pool is open for your kind of exercise. Some hotels do open their pools for non guests but on the other hand, hotel pools might be small and crowded. Municipal pools might only have open lap swimming sessions a few times in the week. Asking locally will result in the best knowledge.

In the US, if a Masters swimmer, you can search for Masters workouts by location. Most will be quite happy to let you swim with them a few days.

@JonCuster Thanks, good to now, I'm a PhD swimmer so I'm sure they'll let me in.

Not sure if you are trying to be funny, but see https://www.usms.org/ for more info.

@JonCuster I'm just tired of hearing exaggerations ("master class", etc.),  but thanks, this is great information!

@FranckDernoncourt - well,  here it just means “old”… (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masters_swimming)

Swimming pools that are open to the public tend to be run by the municipality. You can get a pretty good hit rate by checking the website for the city you are in. For example, here is the page listing pools in Toronto Ontario. It show more facilities than searching for "swimming pool" on Google maps.

OpenStreetMap has a whole series of tags for varieties of swimming and bathing facilities.  It's possible to use them to build queries to search the map, eg search for swimming pools in Torremolinos.
Of course they're only as good as what's been coded up in the map.
